# Flutter : show Dialog don't appear after login failed

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

I have App with login page have this function to login to server ,but when it fails to login the show Dialog did't be shown :

```
signup() async {
    var formdata = formSignUpKey.currentState;
    if (formdata.validate()) {
      formdata.save();
      var data = {
        'username': username.text,
        'password': password.text,
        'email': email.text,
        'nat_id': natId.text
      };
      var url =
          "http://xxx/api/controller/users/register.php";
      var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
      var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (responsebody['status'] == 'success') {
        saveuser(responsebody['username'], responsebody['email']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('index');
      } else {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Error'),
                  content: Text(responsebody['status']),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Close!'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ));
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tested it many time but never shown

Comment: Do you get any error? How do you assign `context`?

Comment: can you print responsebody['status']

Comment: @ShriHari When the login is succeed no error but when it is fail i get this :Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (17652): No data Found

Comment: @Merym when the login is succeed it is print 'success' but when fails nothing printed

Comment: try to put your code in try catch

Comment: @Merym when i used try catch this error found : I/flutter ( 4619): error =  FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Comment: even the login is succeed ?

Comment: @Merym Thanks alot ,i add the show dialog call function inside catch and it is worked correctly ,I will add the solution ,Thank you too much

Comment: up vote to my comment, thanks

Comment: welcome , I did

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after "Merym" asked to put functions inside try catch ,the code  :

```
// Dialog error
_showDialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Error'),
              content: Text('Username or password wrong'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Close me!'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
//login function
  login() async {
    var formdata = formLoginKey.currentState;
    if (formdata.validate()) {
      formdata.save();
      try {
        var data = {'username': username.text, 'password': password.text};
        var url =
            "https://technosat-iq.com/myexpect/api/controller/users/login_user.php";
        var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
        var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print('wooow   ' + responsebody['status']);
        if (responsebody['status'] == 'success') {
          saveuser(responsebody['username'], responsebody['email']);
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('index');
        } else {}
      } catch (err) {
        print('error =  $err');
        _showDialog(context);
      }
    } else {
      print('Bad');
    }
  }
```